# How to bind a style property in a resource to another resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-7.0

I have number of icons that are Paths in a compiled resources dictionary in a WPF app.

```
    <Style x:Key="PathForegroundStyle" TargetType="Shape">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White" />
    </Style>

    <Path x:Shared="False" x:Key="MagnifyingGlass.svg" Data="..." Style="{StaticResource PathForegroundStyle}"/>
```

Which I use like this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource MagnifyingGlass.svg}" />
```

However there are few cases where I need to colour the icon with different/hardcoded colour in a particular control.

The only way I can think of is to have a custom control that had icon name and colour as dependency properties

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: I have resources which are geometries. Use them as data of paths.